# Android: loop for audio not perfect

Tags: android, loops, media-player

In my app I set a mediaplayer with with this instructions:

```
mpBackGround = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.bg_music);
            mpBackGround.setVolume(0.7f, 0.7f);
            mpBackGround.setLooping(true);
            mpBackGround.start();
```

but at the end of first loop I have a little pause between first cycle and second cycle; I also have cut silence spaces in the file (bg_music). With files of type .mid I have not problem but with mp3, wav and other I have this problem...and I have all mp3 files (not midi).
Is there another solution to solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just out of curiosity, is this little pause between the cycles roughly equivalent to the time it takes to seek from one end of the file to the other? It sounds like a performance issue related issue to me.

If thats the case, I would create two instances of media players, and handle the repeating my self. As in, .start() one when the other one finishes. Then you can "rewind" one while the other is playing.

Comment: so you mean that I should create two mediaplayer to organize this loop? When first mediaplayer end second mediaplayer start and viceversa?